# Error Code 1261-- import csv file into mysql workbench 6.2

Tags: mysql, database, csv

I am currently trying to load a large csv file into mysql using workbench 6.2. The issues I keep running into is that I get en error message that says " Error Code: 1261. Row 4670297 doesn't contain data for all columns. Below is the code I am using.

changing `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","` to `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '","'` and there was no difference

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/rates.csv' 
INTO TABLE rates 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Any assistance would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: what's on line 4670297?

Comment: To be honest the file is so large I can't find another program that is able to view that line. All the programs I can find only show me around 1mil lines. This is why I am trying to place it into SQL. unless I am missing something. Thank you for your response.

Comment: `tail -4670298|head -1`. neither needs to deal with the entire file, only one line at a time. it'll be slow counting down that, but should work.

Comment: I'm so sorry but can you please be more specific.

Comment: woops, had those reversed. should be `head -4670297|tail -1`. they're standard unix cli tools. head spits out the specified number of lines from the start of the file, tail works from the end. so. have head spit out the first 4670297 lines of the file, and then have tail spit out only one line from that, which would be the line causing your error.

Comment: oh I see.. I am currently only using windows based machines. I know I need to switch to a unix system this is becoming more obvious. Is there another way I can do this without using a unix command line?

Comment: @asare You could install cygwin or use a windows equivalent command, not sure of one of the top of my head, maybe try SuperUser site

Comment: ok, so based on a coup of suggestions I was able to download cygwyn run a tail command and found that row 4670297 is completely blank there is no data at all. what do I need to do to upload the database based on this new info. Thank you for all your help so far it was very appreciated.

Comment: Ok well I was able to delete that last remaining row and it looks like the database was entered into SQL correctly.. Thank you again for all your assistance.